# How do I merge rows dynamically in R?

Tags: r

I have the following data frame in R:

```
type,status,count
41,438421,512
41,438422,512
41,438429,269
74,440586,172
74,440590,217
```

What I want to do is to merge the rows and rearrange data.  My desired output is shown below:

```
[41] = {["512"] = "438421, 438422", ["269"] = "438429",},
[74] = {["172"] = "440586", ["217"] = "440590",},
```

The rows must be merged so that the type column is unique.  Then the status and counts should be added as shown above.

Note that the values of all these are not known so I can't reference anything by the value (such as 438421).  There are over 100,000 lines in the actual data frame and they all have different values for everything so the solution code needs to work regardless of what values are used above.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you please add to your question to describe that rearranged format? That looks like a particular format (I'm not sure what) and there might be more direct ways of conversion.

Comment: It looked sort of like JSON, in which case you could do something like: `library(tidyverse); library(jsonlite); 
df %>%
  group_by(type, count) %>%
  nest() %>%
  toJSON()`

Comment: The format is just how I want the code to look like.  It doesn't have to be in a table format or anything like that.  It can be just plain text.  With the code in that format, I plan to just copy and paste it into my project.

Comment: WHY do you want to look your data in a way like that? Data should always be in a way that the computer knows what to do with it. What you want is no useful data format.

Comment: Curious why you're using the '=' sign that way, it's pretty non-standard. As @DSGym also just wrote.

Comment: The output data file is actually a code project and with Andrew Gustar's solution, I can create the data file and then copy the whole file into my project without needing to edit it at all.  I didn't want standard table output at all, I just wanted R to output project code and Andrew Gustar's solution is absolutely spot on perfect for my needs and I can't thank him enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `dplyr`...

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(type, count) %>%
  summarise(status = paste(status, collapse = ", ")) %>%
  mutate(count = paste0('["', count, '"] = "', status, '"')) %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarise(count = paste(count, collapse = ", ")) %>%
  mutate(type = paste0('[', type, '] = {', count, ',},')) %>%
  select(type)

  type                                                               
  <chr>                                                              
1 "[41] = {[\"269\"] = \"438429\", [\"512\"] = \"438421, 438422\",},"
2 "[74] = {[\"172\"] = \"440586\", [\"217\"] = \"440590\",},"
```

Don't worry about the backslashes in the above - they are just escaping the literal double quotes for the purposes of printing the output.

Comment: Absolutely splendid, Andrew, thank you so much.  This is perfect and it's exactly what I wanted.  My goal was to have an R script that creates project code (not a table as such) so that I can run it and have it produce a code file ready for use.  Thanks to your solution, Andrew, it all works perfectly now.  You saved me so much hassle and time, my friend, and I can't thank you enough.